# Arduino Pro Mini and Electronic Speed Controller (ESC)

Tags: servo, arduino-pro-mini

I want to send servo signal to ESC and Servo with my 3.3V Arduino Pro Mini.

Can the ESC/Servo read 3.3V signal from Arduino Pro Mini? Or do I need to make some level shifter to make 5V signal?

Answer (score 1):

The ESC should have no problem with 3v3 signal.

Comment: i have 1 more stupid question.. if i use pro mini 5V, is it ok if i power it with regulated 5V to the RAW pin?

Comment: If you put 5V on the RAW pin you will loose voltage over the voltageregulator thats on the Nano, might be as low as 1V or more, depending on the regulator and current draw. If you have 5v regulated use the 5v pin.

Answer (score 0):

Signal can be send easily from Arduino Pro mini to ESC, Simply either use .write() or .Microseconds() function.